# PHP IF OR Else statement - best way to do this

Tags: php, if-statement

I want to know the best way to do a PHP IF OR statement.. but I have a list of arrays over 30+

This is the current format of the array:

```
if($cq=="45" || $cq=="45" || $cq=="35")  {

// action to my function

}
```

I know I can do an array but Array(); does not support conditions..

Thanks

UPDATE - I know it is old, even I know that and I am novice PHP. Look at my profile questions example (blank ones)

This is the code I was left with:

```
if(
                            $cq=="45" || 
                            $cq=="53" || 
                            $cq=="37" || 
                            $cq=="70" || //
                            $cq=="74" || //
                            $cq=="36" || // - this function removes colours if they have this ID
                            $cq=="66" || //
                            $cq=="61" || //
                            $cq=="69" || 
                            $cq=="20" || 
                            $cq=="55" || 
                            $cq=="50")

                            {



                            }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, but are you looking for the `in_array` builtin function?

Comment: I agree with @Artefact2. By the way `$cq=="45" || $cq=="45"` is quite redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$yourArray = ('45', '45', '35'):
if ( in_array($ca, $yourArray) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
$cqs = array("45", "35");
if ( in_array($cq, $cqs) ) {
    // action to your function
}
```

Also you have to concider your variable type - is it integer ? Then remove all of that `"`

Comment: Check the third parameter of the function ;)

Comment: @hakre Sure thing, but always remember about strong typing even if it is not necessery in language. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You do this with array's:

```
$test = array(45,35);

if(in_array($cq,$test)){

    // action to your function

}
```